# Parser - Shift/reduce conflict

Tags: bison, yacc, parser-generator

I have a problem with my parser that is driving me crazy and was wondering if you guys would be able to help me.

I have this set of rules:

```
exp:        exp OP exp
    |       exp OSQUAREPAR exp CSQUAREPAR
    |       exp DOT LENGTH
    |       exp DOT ID OPAR expList CPAR
    |       READERS DOT INTREADER DOT READINT OPAR CPAR
    |       DIGIT
    |       TRUE
    |       FALSE
    |       ID
    |       THIS
    |       NEW INT OSQUAREPAR exp CSQUAREPAR 
    |       NEW ID OPAR CPAR
    |       EXCL exp    
    |       OPAR exp CPAR   
    ;
```

And the following conflict:

> rule 28   exp -> exp OP exp
>
> rule 29   exp -> exp OSQUAREPAR exp CSQUAREPAR
>
> rule 30   exp -> exp DOT LENGTH
>
> rule 31   exp -> exp DOT ID OPAR expList CPAR
>
> rule 32   exp -> READERS DOT INTREADER DOT READINT OPAR CPAR
>
> rule 33   exp -> DIGIT
>
> rule 34   exp -> TRUE
>
> rule 35   exp -> FALSE
>
> rule 36   exp -> ID
>
> rule 37   exp -> THIS
>
> rule 38   exp -> NEW INT OSQUAREPAR exp CSQUAREPAR
>
> rule 39   exp -> NEW ID OPAR CPAR
>
> rule 40   exp -> EXCL exp
>
> rule 41   exp -> OPAR exp CPAR
>
> ```
> state 94
>
> exp  ->  EXCL exp .   (rule 37)
> exp2  ->  exp . OP exp   (rule 39)
> exp2  ->  exp . OSQUAREPAR exp CSQUAREPAR   (rule 40)
> exp2  ->  exp . DOT LENGTH   (rule 41)
> exp2  ->  exp . DOT ID OPAR expList CPAR   (rule 42)
>
> OSQUAREPAR    shift, and go to state 97
> DOT   shift, and go to state 98
> OP    shift, and go to state 99
>
> OSQUAREPAR    [reduce using rule 37 (exp)]
> DOT   [reduce using rule 37 (exp)]
> OP    [reduce using rule 37 (exp)]
> $default  reduce using rule 37 (exp)
> ```

Any ideas of how to solve this problem? I already checked other similar questions and even tried adding a priority to EXCL like one of the answers indicates but can't solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach example (conflict-free):

```
%token DIGIT FALSE ID INT INTREADER LENGTH NEW READERS READINT THIS TRUE

%left  '+' '-'
%left  '*' '/'
%left  UNARY

%%

exp:       unary
   |       exp '+' exp
   |       exp '-' exp
   |       exp '*' exp
   |       exp '/' exp
   ;

expList:    exp
       |    expList ',' exp
       ;

operand:    '(' exp ')'
       |    DIGIT
       |    TRUE
       |    FALSE
       |    ID
       |    THIS
       |    READERS '.' INTREADER '.' READINT '(' ')'
       |    NEW INT '[' exp ']' 
       |    NEW ID '(' ')'
       ;

primary:    operand
       |    primary '[' exp ']'
       |    primary '.' LENGTH
       |    primary '.' ID '(' expList ')'
       ;

unary:      primary
     |      '!' unary
     |      '+' unary
     |      '-' unary %prec UNARY
     ;
```